# Run karma tests in linux terminal

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, karma-runner

I'm building automation proccess for some AngularJS project. As part of flow I have to ran karma tests via grunt test on linux (CentOS) machine without GUI interface. I have no idea how karma works. Can I run it this way?

Answer (score 0):

The [karma-runner for grunt](https://github.com/karma-runner/grunt-karma) has an example of how to configure karma to run with phantom in CI mode(Run the tests once and then exit). You just have to use this configuration in your Gruntfile:

```
karma: {
  unit: {
    configFile: 'karma.conf.js',
    runnerPort: 9999,
    singleRun: true,
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
    logLevel: 'ERROR'
  }
}
```

The browsers array tells karma that you want to use only PhantomJS(No GUI necessary).